# print canvas in new window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

i want to print the canvas in new open window,
it also show in the new window,but when it goes to print();
it's blank like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/torDs.png)

here is my code

```
$('#BPrint').click(function () {

        stage3.toDataURL({
        callback: function (dataUrl) {
            //alert(dataUrl);
        var di = new Image();
        di.src = dataUrl;
        var canvas = document.getElementById("DC");
        canvas.height = di.height;
        canvas.width = di.width;
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        context.drawImage(di, 0, 0);

        var printWin = window.open('', '', 'width=486,height=237');
        $(printWin.document.body).append(di);
        printWin.focus();
        printWin.print()
     ;}

});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the image has been appended to the new window:printWin, the new window does not find the image path, which is pointing to the default window.

Comment: Do you mean i need a path pointing to new window for print()? because image did show on new window.

Comment: I use todataurl() again to the canvas in old page , it works